# How do I run pip on python for windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just installed python 3.5, ran `Python 3.5 (32-bit)` and typed

```
pip
```

and received the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    pip
NameError: name 'pip' is not defined
```

I don't see any scripts directories in my path, but I found `pip.py` in `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts`.

I selected the option to "Add python to environment variables" during installation, but it doesn't seem to have done anything.

I googled this and got [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/197947/how-to-install-python-on-windows/), which says that earlier versions need to add some path names. I don't have a `C:\Python...` directory so I tried adding the `Scripts` folder from above, same result.

How do I install python so that it actually works (ie. I can run pip, install modules, etc.)?

Comment: you need to run pip on cmd not in idle.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I get the same result either way.

Comment: did you move to the folder where pip is actually located?ie, `C:\python\scripts`

Comment: @AvinashRaj I haven't moved any files.

Comment: Did you try Googling "pip python error"? That duplicate question is one of the top hits.

Comment: I ran python.exe to make sure the installation was good, then I ran pip, which gave this error. This seems to be functionally the same as running pip in IDLE. I closed and re-opened CMD and the issue was gone.

Comment: @AvinashRaj What is `cmd` verses `idle`? How would i know if i'm using one over the other? It what case would someone want to use `idle` instead of `cmd`? Why would a command not work it `idle` but work in `cmd`?

Comment: `cmd` are terminal commands which should be run on external terminals like bash, etc. `pip` is an utility for installing python packages which gets installed system-wide or specific to an virtual-environment. And idle is an GUI utility for running python code. Like said in the first answer, we may install packages through a python program, (I'm sure that pip.main will call os function for installing packages) or from a terminal shell (preferred way)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Maybe you'd like try run `pip` in Python shell like this:

```
>>> import pip
>>> pip.main(['install', 'requests'])
```

This will install `requests` package using `pip`.

---

Because `pip` is a module in standard library, but it isn't a built-in function(or module), so you need import it.

Other way, you should run `pip` in system shell(cmd. If `pip` is in path).

Comment: finally working one! :) thanks

Comment: I get the error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    pip.main(['install', 'requests'])
AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'main'`

Comment: UPDATE: Since pip version 10.x there is no more get_installed_distributions() or main method under import pip instead use import pip._internal as pip.

Comment: Had this issue. You can workaround it by running `pip` at the command line as follows: `python -m pip install whatever`. Note that you might need to call python3 instead since this will call the default python(3.6.6 at the time of writing).

Answer (score 19):

I have a Mac, but luckily this should work the same way:

`pip` is a command-line thing. You don't run it in python.

For example, on my Mac, I just say:

`$pip install somelib`

pretty easy!

Comment: Does this mean that the python command line / IDLE ignore your path variables under windows?

Comment: @quant you can use `import os` in Python to mess with path variables. i think that's what you're asking, anyways.

Comment: Python isn't ignoring anything. `pip` simply isn't a Python command, any more than `dir` or `ls` is.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yes, i think that's what OP was asking. OP, pip is a python program that runs from terminal. you don't run it in python.

Answer (score -3):

First go to the pip documentation if not install before:
http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installing/

and follow the install pip which is first download get-pip.py from
https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Then run the following (which may require administrator access):
python get-pip.py

Comment: This is not an "answer" and barely constructive.